# How to Fetch Data By using Two Date Columns in PostgreSQL SQL?

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, linq, date

I m Trying to Fetch Data by using Two Date column in PostgreSQL. It is giving me the correct the output according to the query. But it is not giving me my expected result. 
[image]

In this Output i fetched data by using document_submission_date and received_date of February month but it is giving me some output of the month of march which I indicated with the blue sign. yap, for sure it is giving me the correct result according to the query. but i only want to return all data except the blue indicator (image above). this is my query given below..

```
 SELECT Sum(pd.line_total) AS lc_receive, 
       rbo.rbo_name, 
       pipay.status, 
       rbo.rbo_id, 
       pipay.document_submission_date, 
       pipay.received_date 
FROM   proforma_invoice pi 
       JOIN pi_payment_information pipay 
         ON pi.proforma_invoice_id = pipay.pi_id 
       JOIN proforma_invoice_details pd 
         ON pd.proforma_invoice_id = pi.proforma_invoice_id 
       JOIN product_category pc 
         ON pc.product_category_id = pd.product_category_id 
       JOIN rbo 
         ON pc.rbo_id = rbo.rbo_id 
       JOIN users usr 
         ON pi.created_by = usr.user_id 
       JOIN team_mapping tm 
         ON usr.employee_id = tm.emp_id 
WHERE  tm.team_id = '5' 
       AND ( pipay.status = 'L/C Received' 
              OR pipay.status = 'TT Received' 
              OR pipay.status = 'Bill Received' 
              OR pipay.status = 'FDD Received' 
              OR pipay.status = 'Doc Submitted' 
              OR pipay.status = 'Acceptance Received' ) 
       AND ( To_date(pipay.received_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') BETWEEN 
                   To_date('01/02/2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND 
                   To_date('29/02/2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
              OR ( To_date(pipay.document_submission_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') BETWEEN 
                   To_date( 
                       '01/02/2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND 
                   To_date('29/02/2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
                 ) ) 
       AND pipay.received_date != 'N/A' 
GROUP  BY rbo.rbo_id, 
          rbo.rbo_name, 
          pipay.status, 
          pipay.document_submission_date, 
          pipay.received_date
```

I have been trying to solve this problem since yesterday but i could't find any solution of this. It will be very helpful to me to if any one help me to solve this problem. If anyone help to solve this by Linq Query, that will be helpful too.

Comment: The root cause of the issue is that you are comparing VARCHARs instead of DATEs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work as expected. Consider these conditions in your `WHERE` clause:

```
AND ( 
    To_date(pipay.received_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') BETWEEN 
                   To_date('01/02/2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND 
                   To_date('29/02/2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
    OR ( To_date(pipay.document_submission_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') BETWEEN 
                   To_date('01/02/2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND 
                   To_date('29/02/2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
    )
)
```

This predicates filters on rows where either `received_date` **or** `document_submission_date` belong to the month of February. What you are showing in your current results satisfies these conditions.

If you want both columns in February, use `AND` instead of `OR`. I would also recommend using date literals and half-open intervals as these make the query shorter and easier to read:

```
AND to_date(pipay.received_date,            'DD/MM/YYYY') >= date '2020-02-01'
AND to_date(pipay.received_date,            'DD/MM/YYYY') <  date '2020-03-01'
AND to_date(pipay.document_submission_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') >= date '2020-02-01'
AND to_date(pipay.document_submission_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') <  date '2020-03-01'
```

Side note: you should *really* fix your schema and store date values as `date` datatypes. Storing dates as strings is a bad practice that makes things inefficient and unnecessarily complicated.

---

If you want to all `null`s in `document_submission_date`, then:

```
AND to_date(pipay.received_date,            'DD/MM/YYYY') >= date '2020-02-01'
AND to_date(pipay.received_date,            'DD/MM/YYYY') <  date '2020-03-01'
AND (
    pipay.document_submission_date IS NULL
    OR (
        to_date(pipay.document_submission_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') >= date '2020-02-01'
        AND to_date(pipay.document_submission_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') <  date '2020-03-01'
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this participation. Actually I know it is bad practise but it was designed with character varying. if i change it will impact whole project.  and tried With "AND" also but it remove the null of document_submission_date. and i tried with your answer also it is giving me the same result (remove the null). i just need to remove the row of march. but null will exist of document_submission_date.

Comment: Thanks Bro. Now it worked.. though i used between..  @GMB